# Uploaded animated GIFs suddenly lose animation

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, imgur, uploader

I post a majority of my answers to GameDev. Due to the context of my answers, I often create small diagrams or animations to help other users. Today, I noticed that an animated GIF I uploaded was not animating. Further tests confirm that this appears to be a bug.

I have also confirmed the same behaviour on Stack Overflow, English Language Learners, Science Fiction & Fantasy and here on meta.

---

***Are you sure it is not just your computer?*** Yes. Animations work fine, otherwise. Furthermore, [answers where I have previously uploaded animated diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/unity3d/7827/vector3) are still animating.

***Why can't you just provide anonymous links?*** Actually, I can. It appears that if I upload an image via an anonymous account, and then use the direct link to upload the same image to the Stack Overflow account, it works. Regardless, this process is a bit obtuse, and it still highlights the presence of a bug.

***Could it be an issue with the imposed size limits?*** While animation naturally infers an increased size limit, these animations *all* fall under the maximum of 2MB. I have confirmed this problem on animations ranging from approximately 50kB to 500kB.

***Changing the size of your uploaded image with '-s', '-m' or '-l' cancels animation? Sounds like you have your answer.*** Not by a long shot. I made the mistake of assigning the "medium" variant of my original images, *for the purpose of demonstrating the difference in this question*. This has been corrected, but it does not solve the actual bug I am observing. Both of the below examples come from the exact same image, and should *both* be animating.

***Are you sure it is not a problem with imgur?*** Yes. If I upload the same image via an anonymous account, it animates. I directly uploaded the left version of the image, where I uploaded the right version directly to an anonymous imgur account and provided the link.

[image: If I upload an animated image via the Stack Exchange, it loses animation.] [image: If I upload an animated image via an anonymous account, and transfer it over to the Stack Exchange account via link, it works.]

Comment: with the images you have posted is the right one supposed to animate? because both don't for me

Comment: Could probably post that as an answer. I *extensively* use gifs in answers, and I didn't know about this.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, let me clarify again. **The bug is still there**; to make my question more readable, I edited it to ammend the *"m"* to the .gif url. This *outright* removes animation. **I still do not have animation in gifs uploaded through Stack Exchange; BOTH above examples are of the same animated image**.

Comment: Maybe on purpose, to block people from uploading animations as their avatar. (it's possible by exploiting imgur bug)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, they are not blocking animations *outright*, if they are. When you upload an image, you can upload from your computer, or via a link. Either way, the image provided will be uploaded to the *Stack Exchange* account, and linked. *If the animation is provided via link*, animation retains. *If I upload from a computer*, it does not.

Comment: Well, something is surely weird, hopefully someone from the team will shed some light soon then.

Comment: I'll be honest, this was a very weird bug, and very annoying. I found a way around it through writing this actual question (talk about efficiency, guys!), but the bug is still there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, that was me, sorry about that.

Basically, I've changed some Image Uploading code because on [Stack Overflow Enterprise](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise), we don't use the Imgur host that the public sites use, which means that we have two different ways of handling image uploads.

Since [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is a good thing and since there was a bug in the code, I combined some of it and broke animated GIF upload in the process.

I've undone the breaking change.

[image: GIFs be animated again!]